# Chrome Headless doesn't work on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, chromium, google-chrome-headless

I'm desperately trying to make Chrome Headless work on my production server (Ubuntu 16.04).

When I run the following command:

> google-chrome --headless --disable-gpu --dump-dom http://www.example.org/

The DOM will be dumped only when I run it as `root` with the `--no-sandbox` flag. When running it with another user, here's the output:

```
[0312/110057.072748:ERROR:gpu_process_transport_factory.cc(1019)] Lost UI shared context.
<html><head></head><body></body></html>
```

I have tried with `google-chrome-stable` and `chromium-browser`, same result: it only works as `root` with the `--no-sandbox` flag.

I don't think it's a dependency problem since it works properly as root.

I have setup an Ubuntu 16.04 VM and can make it work on it with any user, I just don't succeed on my production server.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having some troubles running as a non-root user too.